# Can't connect to Samba/LDAP share, no obvious error

Tags: debian, ldap, samba

I just did an initial Samba/LDAP configuration on a Debian Squeeze system. I added a single user to an ldap directory and installed libnss-ldap. I can now successfully login to the system using the newly created user, so it seems that Debian itself has no problem authenticating with LDAP.

I configured Samba based on a number of tutorials, but I haven't been able to connect to a share since I've configured LDAP. Here is the smb.conf:

```
[global]
    workgroup = ANDROCS
    passdb backend = ldapsam:ldap://127.0.0.1/

    log level = 5
    log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
    max log size = 100

    time server = Yes

    domain logons = Yes
    preferred master = Yes
    domain master = Yes
    wins support = No

    # LDAP
    ldap admin dn = cn=admin,dc=androcs,dc=com
    ldap group suffix = ou=group
    ldap idmap suffix = ou=Idmap
    ldap machine suffix = ou=Computers
    ldap passwd sync = Yes
    ldap suffix = dc=androcs,dc=com
    ldap user suffix = ou=Users
    ldap ssl = off

    idmap backend = ldap:ldap://127.0.0.1
    idmap uid = 10000-20000
    idmap gid = 10000-20000


# now define some shares
[technical]
    comment = Common Engineering and Technical Material
    path = /export/technical
    force group = technical
    read only = No
    create mask = 0770
    directory mask = 0770
    browseable = No

[development]
    comment = Software Development Repositories
    path = /export/development
    force group = development
    read only = No
    create mask = 0770
    directory mask = 0770
    browseable = No

[business]
    comment = Common Business Material
    path = /export/business
    force group = business
    read only = No
    create mask = 0770
    directory mask = 0770
    browseable = No
```

So I try logging onto the share from another Debian system using the gnome 'Connect to server' function. Simultaneously I tail the output of the syslog, and here is the result:

```
Jul 29 11:27:34 androserve slapd[3038]: conn=1004 fd=13 ACCEPT from IP=127.0.0.1:53334 (IP=0.0.0.0:389)
Jul 29 11:27:34 androserve slapd[3038]: conn=1004 op=0 BIND dn="cn=admin,dc=androcs,dc=com" method=128
Jul 29 11:27:34 androserve slapd[3038]: conn=1004 op=0 BIND dn="cn=admin,dc=androcs,dc=com" mech=SIMPLE ssf=0
Jul 29 11:27:34 androserve slapd[3038]: conn=1004 op=0 RESULT tag=97 err=0 text=
Jul 29 11:27:34 androserve slapd[3038]: conn=1004 op=1 SRCH base="" scope=0 deref=0 filter="(objectClass=*)"
Jul 29 11:27:34 androserve slapd[3038]: conn=1004 op=1 SRCH attr=supportedControl
Jul 29 11:27:34 androserve slapd[3038]: conn=1004 op=1 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=1 text=
Jul 29 11:27:34 androserve slapd[3038]: conn=1004 op=2 SRCH base="dc=androcs,dc=com" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(uid=tarcuri)(?objectClass=sambaSamAccount))"
Jul 29 11:27:34 androserve slapd[3038]: conn=1004 op=2 SRCH attr=uid uidNumber gidNumber homeDirectory sambaPwdLastSet sambaPwdCanChange sambaPwdMustChange sambaLogonTime sambaLogoffTime sambaKickoffTime cn sn displayName sambaHomeDrive sambaHomePath sambaLogonScript sambaProfilePath description sambaUserWorkstations sambaSID sambaPrimaryGroupSID sambaLMPassword sambaNTPassword sambaDomainName objectClass sambaAcctFlags sambaMungedDial sambaBadPasswordCount sambaBadPasswordTime sambaPasswordHistory modifyTimestamp sambaLogonHours modifyTimestamp uidNumber gidNumber homeDirectory loginShell gecos
Jul 29 11:27:34 androserve slapd[3038]: conn=1004 op=2 SEARCH RESULT tag=101 err=0 nentries=0 text=
Jul 29 11:27:34 androserve slapd[3038]: conn=1004 fd=13 closed (connection lost)
```

The line the immediately sticks out to me is:

```
conn=1004 op=2 SRCH base="dc=androcs,dc=com" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(uid=tarcuri)(?objectClass=sambaSamAccount))"
```

In particular the `objectClass`. I am new to LDAP, but I configured the user as `person`, `inetOrgPerson`, `posixAccount`, and `shadowAccount`.

Does anyone know where I should start? Can I increase the logging level to get a better clue as to what is wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search filter looks suspect because of the `'?'` before the text `objectClass` but that might be a translation or pasting error. The search returned zero entries (`nentries=0`) because as you said, no entries had a `uid` of `tarcuri` *and* an objectClass of `sambaSamAccount`.

Comment: So what does that mean? How does gnome decide which `objectClass` to use?

Comment: I know nothing about Samba, but it appears that the application uses the `sambaSamAccount` objectClass to locate users. You must add that objectClass to the entries, along with whatever attributes are required by the sambaSamAccount objectClass. Try adding `objectClass: sambaSamAccount` to the `tarcuri` entry. The objectClass might require some other attributes, those would be defined in the schema.

Comment: Simply removing the space at the end of the name did the trick! Much appreciated!

Comment: I live to serve